# Как решить проблему выделения BUTTON в Мозилле при нажатии?

Tags: css, button, firefox

В Мозилле при нажатии на кнопку (`<button></button>`)она выделяется в какую-то непонятную
чёрную пунктирную рамку, и также текст кнопки на пару пикселей сдвигается вправо:

[image]

Можно ли как-то избавиться от этих ненужных вещей? Есть ли какие-то для этого CSS-стили?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. А насчёт сдвига текста вправо не подскажите?

Comment: Попробуйте вот это:  
button:active {  
margin: 0;  
padding: 0;  
}  

А вообще, лучше соберите пример на jsFiddle

Comment: padding:0 помог.